# Группировка и фильтрация массива по нескольким признакам JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, map-reduce

Дан некий массив объектов:

```
    const arr = [
  {
    method: 1,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 10,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 100,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 49,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 33,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'USD',
    amount: 55,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 77,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'USD',
    amount: 47,
    priority: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'USD',
    amount: 57,
    priority: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    method: 5,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 140,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 37,
    method: 5,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 22,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    method: 3,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 100,
    priority: 1,
  },
]
```

Массив может быть сколь угодно большим. Стоит задача выбрать из него только "актуальные" элементы. То есть, нужно сначала сгруппировать элементы по method, currency, priority, а затем в каждой группе забрать только те элементы, у которых amount > 50 + элемент группы, у которого amount < 50, но самый большой в группе. Нужные элементы вынести в отдельный массив.

Иными словами нужно сначала определить элементы с одинаковым методом, валютой и приоритетом и из них забрать только те, у которых сумма больше 50 и элемент с суммой меньше 50, но больше всех остальных в этой группе.

По массиву из примера результат должен быть следующим:

```
    result = [
  {
    id: 22,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 100,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 49,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 33,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'USD',
    amount: 55,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'USD',
    amount: 57,
    priority: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 77,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'USD',
    amount: 47,
    priority: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    method: 5,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 140,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 37,
    method: 5,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 22,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    method: 3,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 100,
    priority: 1,
  },
]
```

Не могу ещё в такую сложную (для меня) группировку элементов массива, прошу помощи. Мне нужен именно алгоритм такой фильтрации. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: какой результат ожидается для этого массива?

Comment: @Grundy сейчас добавлю в вопрос ожидаемый результат

Comment: @Grundy обновил исходный массив (для большей наглядности) и добавил ожидаемый результат

Comment: @bomberman90 Я не очень понял на счёт группировки. Вам же по сути нужны просто элементы, у которых `amount > 50`, нет? И получается тогда, что фильтрация нужна только по одному критерию

Comment: @EzioMercer нет, немного не верно. Мне нужно сначала определить группы, то есть выбрать все элементы с одинаковым method, currency и priority и уже среди них выбрать те, что больше 50. То есть, сначала ищем тех, у кого, например, method = 1, currency - RUB, prority = 1. А уже внутри этой группы отсеиваем по amount. Я понял откуда Ваш вопрос - в примере достаточно просто фильтрации по амаунту, но мне нужен именно описанный алгоритм

Comment: @bomberman90 А куда потом девается группа? В чём разница группировать и из каждой группы взять те у кого `amount > 50` или просто сразу взять всех тех у кого `amount > 50`? Вот к примеру из вашего же входного массива, по вашему алгоритму я должен объеденить в некую группу 1-ый и 2-ой элемент, и только потом достать из этой группы 2-ой элемент, когда как я могу сразу его достать не делая лишних действий

Comment: @EzioMercer я уже понял, что указанный пример некорректен и ваш вывод верный. Я старался упростить свою задачу для примера, чтобы получить алгоритм сортировки. Изначально моя задача звучит как "забрать все элементы группы с amount > 50 + элемент у которого amount < 50 но больше всех остальных в группе". Добавлю это в вопрос.

Comment: @EzioMercer спасибо за замечания! Исправил описание и ожидаемый результат

Comment: @bomberman90 Теперь всё стало намного понятнее, зачем вам эти группы :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135494/discussion-between-eziomercer-and-bomberman90).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная идея - это группировать по единому ключу, который является объединением нужных для группировки св-в и уникальным для каждой группы, остальное элементарно:

- Все у кого `amount > 50` автоматом попадают в конечный массив
- Далее по одному смотрим не тех у кого `amount <= 50`. Если он первый то запоминаем его, если не первый то сравниваем с тем что уже хранится, если у нового `amount` больше чем у сохранённого то делаем замену иначе просто пропускаем

Вот реализация:

```js
const arr = [{
    method: 1,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 10,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 100,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 49,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 33,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'USD',
    amount: 55,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 77,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'USD',
    amount: 47,
    priority: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    method: 1,
    currency: 'USD',
    amount: 57,
    priority: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    method: 5,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 140,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 37,
    method: 5,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 22,
    priority: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    method: 3,
    currency: 'RUB',
    amount: 100,
    priority: 1,
  },
];

const groups = new Map();
const filteredArr = [];

arr.forEach(item => {
  const isAmountBig = item.amount > 50;

  if (isAmountBig) {
    filteredArr.push(item);
    return;
  }

  const key = `${item.method}-${item.currency}-${item.priority}`;

  if (!groups.has(key)) {
    groups.set(key, {maxValue: item.amount, item});
    return;
  }

  const group = groups.get(key);

  if (item.amount <= group.maxValue) return;

  group.maxValue = item.amount;
  group.item = item;
});

[...groups.values()].forEach(groupItem => filteredArr.push(groupItem.item));

console.log(filteredArr);
```

P.S. При желании `new Map()` можно спокойно заменить обычным объектом, логика не пострадает, только надо будет переписать пару строк

Comment: Спасибо большое! То, что надо!

Comment: @bomberman90 Обращайтесь!)